# Fill ComboBox with data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to fill a ComboBox with data from sql server and I use the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
protected void FillComboBox()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ItemName FROM TBItemList", oSqlConn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    {
         cbxparameter.Items.Add(dt.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then to make sure my code is okay I'm trying to debug, but I can't know where the trouble lies. Why?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a DataTable, since as far as I can see you are only fetching rows from a single column? Why not use a simple list of strings instead (assuming "ItemName" is of type string) and then bind that list to the ItemsSource property of your combobox.

Comment: how to use that like you say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ItemName FROM TBItemList", oSqlConn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
cbxparameter.DataSource = dt;
cbxparameter.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
cbxparameter.ValueMember = "ItemName";
```

Comment: i mean, still can't show in combobox, and your code can get value from database same with my code, but still can't show...

Comment: it will be working fine. may be you debug the code there is something other things missing

Comment: post your complete code syntax for combobox from aspx page or wherever you are using it. I also don't see any problem with this solution. it should work. @MuhammadIbnuSaefullah

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                MyDDLst.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
                while (dr.Read())
                    MyDDLst.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
```

Comment: try this Muhammad Ibnu Saefullah